# Duplicate detections by the tensorflow API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm currently using the tensorflow object detection API, however while creating bounding boxes on an images, the API tends to make multiple bounding boxes on a single item. Is there anyway I can make it such that only a single unique bounding box is created over a single item.

The current model I'm using for the object detection is a faster rcnn model trained on the open images dataset (from the g3doc model zoo)

Comment: This is a common problem in many object detection algorithm, have try to use  Non-Maximum Suppression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this go to research>object-detection>utils>visualisation_utils.py, and change the min_score_threshold value:

```
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    boxes,
    classes,
    scores,
    category_index,
    instance_masks=None,
    instance_boundaries=None,
    keypoints=None,
    use_normalized_coordinates=False,
    max_boxes_to_draw=20,
    min_score_thresh=.90,
    agnostic_mode=False,
    line_thickness=4,
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
    skip_scores=False,
    skip_labels=False):
```

In my case I use threshold values which are greater than 90 percent. This removes the other bounding boxes with lower probability also as a add-on you can change boarder thickness and colour of bounding box  by using the above script

Comment: I ended up changing the 2nd round thresholds to above 90 so that only the initial bounding boxes remain. As long as the item is distinct (which it usually is in my use case) I seem to be able to detect it in the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this is the standard behavior of detectors. Let's say they are noisy and depending on how the box is placed, the same item can be detected multiple times as different objects.

This is why I think detectors need a filtering function which filters out incorrect predictions. You can easily do something like that using the concept of **IoU**: intersection over union. An example can be found [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/07/intersection-over-union-iou-for-object-detection/), there's also some code you can use.

Basically, perform the detection using your frozen model in the usual way. Then, perform a check on the predicted boxes and discard the ones who somehow are overlayed, i. e. you can discard the overlayed box with lower confidence score with respect to the other one.

Hope it helps!